# gnu c++ floating number precision

Tags: c++

I have simple question about floating number,

```
double temp;  
std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
temp = 12345678901234567890.1234567890;
std::cout << (temp < std::numeric_limits<double>::max()) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::endl;
std::cout << temp << std::endl;
```

However, the output I get is this,

```
1
12345678901234567168.000000000000000
```

The value of temp is still within the range of double, however, the value is completely different. I am wondering what have I done wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) has only 15.95 decimal digits of precision. You've already exceeded this number of digits in the integer part of the value, hence the loss of precision in the last few digits, and the lack of any useful digits after the decimal point.

You should probably take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html before doing any more work with floating point values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how can I improve this precision?

Comment: How much precision do you actually need ?

Comment: @2607: http://www.mpfr.org/, but it is much harder to use than mere doubles. And less efficient.

Comment: Well even quad precision only gives you 34 decimal digits, so if you *really* need 40 then you'll need to use an arbitrary precision library.

Comment: I am a little bit confused about this. If the std::numeric_limits<double>::max() is something like 1E+37, then why the accuracy of double is much lower than that?

Comment: Why are you using floating point types to store integers anyway? You're trying to turn a screw with a hammer. The accuracy is about 16 digits. The `max` is the largest number it can hold, which has nothing to do with how precise it is.

Comment: @2607: You are confusing the *range* of a floating point type with its *precision* - they are two entirely different things.

Comment: I am trying to store a floating number, which can go as far as in the sample code, is there any way that I can tell if a floating number is beyond its accuracy? Or is there any other way you would recommend for storing a large floating number? thanks.

Comment: @2607: A number can only be within its range. Whether or not something is within its accuracy depends on the *precision* needed. `1` is beyond its accuracy if you care that it's not `1.000000000000001`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely different. It's correct to 16 digits or so. That's about what you can expect from a `double`.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can test whether a number is still in the safe range? thanks.

Comment: That's not a meaningful concept. Is 1 in the safe range? Well, that depends if it's important that it's `1.00000000000000` and not `1.000000000000001`. It keeps 16 digits or so. If that's enough for the accuracy you need, the number is safe. If not, not. Digits after the decimal place are just as important as digits before it.

Answer (score 0):

A double can only store a limited amount of precision. It works out to about 15 decimal digits.

Here's a helpful article on how floating point numbers are represented, and the implications of that representation: **[Float](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/float.html)**

Answer (score 0):

IEEE 754 is not precise for any given value - for example http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point.html and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/42980

-358974.27 can't be represented on `float` according to http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/float.html and I remember (though I'm too lazy to test it) that even something "simple" like 2.2 or 2.3 can't be accurately represented even as a `double`.

Comment: 1/10 (decimal) is a repeating fraction in binary, just like 1/3 is a repeating fraction in decimal.